# How to create a conda environment that can switch between arm64 and x86_64 architecture?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using an Apple Mac M1 with MacOS Monterey

I want to create a virtual environment with conda and be able to switch between arm64 and x86_64 architecture. for example

```
arm64 python3 run.py
```

or

```
x86_64 python3 run.py
```

currently i am stuck at this error

> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

the full traceback is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 857, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/onnx/config.py", line 35, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 857, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlm/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .configuration_layoutlm import LAYOUTLM_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, LayoutLMConfig
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlm/configuration_layoutlm.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ...onnx import OnnxConfig, PatchingSpec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1039, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 847, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 859, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.onnx.config because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
dlopen(/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transformers import TFAutoModel, AutoTokenizer
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1039, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 847, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 859, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.auto because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import transformers.onnx.config because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
dlopen(/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

How can I create a conda environment that can switch between arm64 and x86_64 architectures?

Comment: I don't know that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You must create two separate environments.